# Hibernate, Inserting a Grandchild only updates Grandparent -> Parent not updated

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, parent-child, cascade

I have the following structure of bidirectional relations in hibernate. I am using objects named `Grandparent`, `Parent` and `Child`. As one would expect, the `Grandparent` has a list of `Parent` which itself has a list of `Child`.

The problem arises when I try to insert a new `Child` then the change is not propagated to the `parentRepository` but funnily enough it is propagated to the `grandparentRepository`

Please note that I am using Kotlin and thus we have explicit Nullability.

```
@Entity(name = "grandparent")
data class Grandparent(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1
    @NotNull var name: String,
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE],
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "factoryHall",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @NotNull var parents: MutableList<Parent>,
) 

@Entity(name = "parent")
data class Parent(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE],
            optional = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="grandparent_id")
    var grandparent: Grandparent? = null,
    @NotNull var name: String,
    @OneToMany(
            cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE],
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "factoryHall",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @NotNull var children: MutableList<Child>,
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "{" +
                    "id: " + id + ", " +
                    "name: " + name + ", " +
                    "children: " + children.toString() + ", " +
                "}"
    }
}

@Entity(name = "child")
data class Child(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long = -1
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE],
            optional = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(name="child_id")
    var Parent: Parent? = null,
    @NotNull var name: String,
) {
    override fun toString(): String {
            return "{" +
                        "id: " + id + ", " +
                        "name: " + name + ", " +
                    "}"
    }
}
```

I Am trying to populate the Database like this

```
var savedGrandparent = grandparentRepository.save(grandparent)
for(parent in grandparent.parents){
    var savedParent = parentRepository.save(Parent(savedPlant, parent.name, parent.children))
    for(child in parent.children){
        childRepository.save(Child(savedParent, child.name))
    }
}
```

That simply means that I am first saving a parental object and then saving the corresponding child objects with their parent attribute set.
This way I later have a populated `grandparentRepository` where all the `Grandparents` have the list of `Parents` populated and those have their list of `Children` populated.

However in the `parentRepository` the list of `Children` of each `Parent` is not populated.

Sadly a onedirectional relation (which would easily solve this problem) does not allow for a propagation of deleted child objects so this one is out of the picture.

Can anyone enlighten me on what happens here and what the best way to tackle this is?